# How to change size in MPAndroidChart PieChart color indicator color squar

Tags: pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to increase size of MPAndroidChart PieChart color indicator color squar mentioned in blow image

[image]

Comment: add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the chart that you are talking about is the `Legend`.

There are various ways of styling it which can be found in the [**documentation**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend).

You can set text size and color and many other things.